# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. React Native

Tags: react-native, key, flatlist

Hello i'm trying to build a mini social media app with react native, getting the following error:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of VirtualizedList

tried to use results.map instead of flat list also.
and also to change the key extractor with solutions on stackoverflow, but no success.
anyone can help please ?

code:

```
    return (
    <FlatList
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={results}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
        return item.id;
      }} 
      renderItem={({item}) => <TouristCard key={item.id} item={item} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('HomeProfile', {userId: item.userId})} /> }
    />
);
```

TouristCard:

const TouristCard = ({item,onPress}) => {

```
return (   
    <View key={item.id} style={styles.listItem} >
      <UserImg  source={{uri: item.userImg ? item.userImg : 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0PKyNuQv5s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclxAM4M1SCBGAO7Rp-QP6zgBEUkOQ/s96-c/photo.jpg'}}/>
      <View style={{alignItems:"center",flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{item.fname ? item.fname : 'Annonymous' } {item.lname ? item.lname : '' }</Text>
        <Text>{item.flightDesc}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{item.age}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{color:"blue"}}>View Profile</Text>
    </View>
);
```

results object:

```
   const filterByDates = (results,startDate,endDate) => {
    return results.filter(res => {
        return startDate<res.endDate && res.startDate<endDate;
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCommunity = async() => {
        try {
            //const list = [];
            await firestore()
            .collection('flights')
            .where("destination","==",destination)
            .where("user","!=",user.uid)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapShot) => {
                querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
                    const {user,flightDesc,startDate,endDate} = doc.data();
                    list.push({
                        user: user,
                        flightDesc,
                        startDate,
                        endDate
                    });
                })
                
            })  
            setResults(filterByDates(list,startDate,endDate));
            fetchProfiles();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    const fetchProfiles = async() => {
        try {
            //const list2=[];
            list.forEach(async obj => {
                await firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .where("userId","==",obj.user)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapShot) => {
                querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
                    const {userImg,age,fname,lname} = doc.data();
                    list.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        userImg,
                        age,
                        fname,
                        lname
                    });
                })
                
            })  
            setResults(list);
            console.log(list);
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    fetchCommunity();
},[]);
```

Comment: Have you verified yet that the key extractor actually returns a unique id for each element like you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Flatlist` with this.

```
<FlatList
   style={{flex:1}}
   data={results}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()} // Here was the error
   renderItem={({item}) => <TouristCard item={item} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('HomeProfile', {userId: item.userId})} /> }
/>
```

Also check whether each element of your `results` has a unique `id` or not?

And `MAIN` point... Check does your array items has a property called `id` or not..and if `userId` is unique then use that as shown above

Comment: now I get this error: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.userId.toString')]

Comment: Edited the answer check again

Comment: If you still have problem then please post your `results` in the question.. What does it look like?

Comment: I posted it, still same, help please, checked it , the results isn't empty, the key is unique, but the key extractor looks like empty, it doesn't read the toString(), says its undefined.

Comment: I was not asking for this... Just `console.log(results)` and show me the output

Comment: [{"endDate": "12/04/2021", "flightDesc": undefined, "id": "6Od5e7QTg0wNMOUdX18h", "startDate": "05/04/2021", "user": "XMlJXka3bqMiTASxdWscA9qKlIl1"}, {"age": "23", "fname": "Tami", "lname": "Balilti", "userImg": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flywithme-app.appspot.com/o/photos%2F1de95821-894b-4c96-8db8-d4ea4d21683a1619011385670.jpg?alt=media&token=30f45172-ef97-444d-9ebe-a710350dee77"}]

Comment: As you can see there is no `id` in 1st element of `array`..This is causing the error

Comment: tried to fix that on the following code above to be first, but endDate anyway get stuck first, idk why

Comment: changed it like that: [{"id": "6Od5e7QTg0wNMOUdX18h", "startDate": "05/04/2021", "user": "XMlJXka3bqMiTASxdWscA9qKlIl1"}, {"age": "23", "fname": "Tami", "lname": "Balilti", "userImg": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flywithme-app.appspot.com/o/photos%2F1de95821-894b-4c96-8db8-d4ea4d21683a1619011385670.jpg?alt=media&token=30f45172-ef97-444d-9ebe-a710350dee77"}] still same problem

Comment: Still it won't work.. Unless each element of the array has a unique field called `id`

Comment: Oh, I understand my problem, tried to implement like inner join with firebase, new to firebase, it made two separates objects in my list, i will try to change it to one object, than it will work?

Comment: Yup, it will always work if each element of the array has a unique `id`. Ping me if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank you mate! do you know how can I change my code to be one object when searching? like Inner join? if not anyway thanks ! <3 helped me alot

Comment: I am new to `firebase`...Sorry!